# Invalid filter name "Javascript" in HAML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

While writing some HAML for a Rails application, I tried to use the :javascript filter to embed some inline javascript into the document. Whenever I try to load the page, Rails complains with `Invalid filter name ":javas­cript".` The code I am trying to include is the following:

```
:javas­cript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#variants').editableTableWidget();
  });
```

Why is rails complaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have somehow got an extra character in your code, a [“soft hyphen” (U+00AD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen), between the `s` and `c` of “javascript”. It doesn’t show up in the HTML, but copying your code and pasting into the terminal to run it reveals the extra character, and the error message appears as

```
Invalid filter name ":javas-cript".
```

(here I’ve replaced the soft hyphen with a normal one so that it shows up in the HTML)

It might not show up in your editor, but if you advance your cursor over the word one character at a time you may notice you need an extra key press between the `s` and `c`.

To fix it, just delete this extra character. If you can’t find it or are unsure, delete the whole `javascript` and retype it.